# Help me calculate the probability and the related questions.

Tags: probability, statistics

So I'll write down the question first-

In a firm employing 50 individuals the probability of Bob being selected as the best employee is half to that of others. What is the probability of Bob being selected as the best employee ?

And if all the 50 employees get the benefit in case of injury and the probability of bob getting injured and then getting the benefit is half than the probability of the others, what is the probability of bob getting the benefit.

So I approached the question using the simple technique and reached the conclusion of $\cfrac1{100} (\cfrac{(\frac{1}{2})}{50})$ but the answer is wrong. Do I have to apply permutation and combination or Bayes theorem to get the answer?

Comment: **Hint:** The sum of the probabilities of each employee receiving the best employee reward must equal $1$.  If the probability Bob wins the award is $p$, then what is the probability that another employee wins the award?

Comment: Suppose you play a two-player game with Bob where exactly one of you will win, and Bob has half as much chance to win as you have. What is Bob's chance to win? Do you apply your "simple technique" and conclude that Bob has $1/4$ chance to win? What's your chance to win, then?

Comment: The second part of the question (about injury and a benefit) seems to lack sufficient information. It is possible that more than one person is injured. It is possible that nobody is injured. On second thought even the first part is ambiguous, since several people may be selected as "best employee" one after the other while Bob is working for the same firm.

Answer (score 1):

First question: if Bob's probability is the half of the other 49 this means that

$$49\times 2p+p=1$$

$$p=\frac{1}{99}$$

Now you can proceed with the second question

Comment: I think the second part of the question will have the same answer of 1/99 as its basically a same question